# is this xml a valid one?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

Me and my coworker got into an argument about xml validity.
I'm very confident that xml node can have either text or other xml nodes, but not both:

In other words - Is this a valid xml? (I'm saying it's NOT)

```
<dt>
    blah blah text   
    <test0>
        some node content
    </test0>
    <test1>
        blah blah some text <some_node>A</some_node>
    </test1>
    <test2>
        noncount
    </test2>
    <test3>
        blah blah some text <some_node>B</some_node>
    </test3>
</dt>
```

EDIT: My coworker argues that since .dtd file has #PCDATA in it like so:

```
<!ELEMENT dt (#PCDATA | test0 | test1 | test2 | test3)* >
```

It means there could be other xml tags inside of it, as well as text.

Comment: It is valid. You can use online validator like this: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: Why then PHP's simpleXml parser strips these inline tags when mixed with text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a distinction in XML between something being well-formed and something being valid. Sometimes people say valid when they mean well-formed, which is confusing. XML is a set of syntactical rules for constructing a vocabulary. On its own, XML says nothing about what elements and attributes are allowed, or where you can put them. If a document adheres to the XML syntax, it is well-formed. Your example is well-formed XML.

Validity means that the particular elements and attributes used are all used in accordance with some DTD or schema. You gave this example DTD snippet:

```
<!ELEMENT dt (#PCDATA | test0 | test1 | test2 | test3)* >
```

Your coworker is correct that the XML you gave is valid according to that DTD (assuming, of course, that the content of all the test elements is valid). If your DTD looked like this instead:

```
<!ELEMENT dt (test0 | test1 | test2 | test3)* >
```

Then your example would not be valid, but it would still be well-formed.

In actual practice, mixing text and child elements is extremely common.

Comment: Why would PHP's simpleXml parser strip these inline tags when mixed with text?

Comment: @user2568737 I suggest you ask the creators of that software. I also suggest that you read specifications for formats rather than relying on the behaviour of a random piece of software you like.

Answer (score 3):

This is *well formed* XML. Text nodes are totally fine, also if mixed if others, which is called ["mixed content"](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content).

Valid XML requires an XML Schema or DTD to be defined which is missing in your snippet.  If you add one which prohibits mixed content it would stay well formed XML, just not following that schema.

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrect.

XML content can contain mixtures of elements and text (character data).

You can find examples of that in any XHTML document.

Comment: HTML documents are not necesserily valid XML documents.

Comment: Slaks said XHTML, not HTML. XHTML documents are well-formed XML documents by definition.